# "Forgot password?" or "Reset password"?

Tags: login, password

We're designing a minimalist login page that follows Google's Material design guidelines.
Near the password field, there is an icon with a link to the Reset password page. For such link, what name is recommended/considered best practice?: "Forgot password?", "Reset password", or something else?

Comment: I've used "Forgot password?" on the login page, with a "reset password" on the actual password recovery page and email. As in "Did you *forget* your password? Do this to *reset* it."

Comment: Well, you *could* decide to provide different means of authentication (e.g. OpenID). In that case a *Forgot password?* link could simply bring the user to a page where he can choose an OpenID to use, *or* reset the password. So it's more general and does not (necessarily) prescribe a password reset action by itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depends:
  When user is not logged in, on login page, it should be **Forgot password**. Since the user is probably not able to login since it forgot/lost the password. Also, there are non technical users that will align and understand better with forgot, rather than reset.

Using forgot, kinds of offer help to the user, while reset is a command like link, for more tech users.

You have the optional ability to inform the user on the next step (page/modal) about next steps they need to do. Usually the best approach is to send password reset link to their email.

Comment: Thanks! I just had a user come back after 4 years who couldn't find the reset link because he was looking for "Forgot Password" instead of what it says, "Reset Password". Changing it now!

Answer (score 3):

I just checked my account, and Google themselves uses "Forgot Password?" So, I'd go with that.

EDIT: Obviously I wouldn't normally just do whatever Google does, as they are not the be-all end-all, but since they specified that they were following Material Design Guidelines, I thought best practice would be to stick to the standard that has been set by them.

Comment: I'd be wary in general of using Google products as examples of sensible UX, although in this case their choice makes sense. I'm surprised they actually wrote "Forgot Password" though instead of just using some incomprehensible icon in a circle.